# Import csv file from local to EC2

Tags: python, django, upload

I am working on Django. I want to get csv file from remote system. My code is running on ec2. I want to import file on ec2 server. How I can do from Django.

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
        file = request.FILES['file']
        fs.save(file.name, file)

    return HttpResponse("status")
```

It will store the file as tempfile and I can't read this file.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Elaborate on the initial location of the file, what you want to do with it, etc. Also, you need to show some efforts on your end, it may just be research efforts to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can open files from any given url with urllib. Example code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen    

with urlopen(URL_OF_FILE) as file:

    csv_file = file.read()
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file.decode('utf-8').splitlines())

    for row in reader:
        # Do something
```